# Using XML call to find elements on a webpage that aren't in the source HTML

Tags: python, html, xml, scrapy

I'm scraping some of the ratings for different drugs on WebMD. When I go to a ratings page (e.g. [here](http://www.webmd.com/drugs/drugreview-8603-Celexa+oral.aspx?drugid=8603&drugname=Celexa%20oral)) there are averages of the total user reviews (the 3.64, 4.33, and 3.40). I am trying to pull them using

```
page.xpath("//p[@id='EaseOfUseSummaryValue']/text()")
```

(for the first number) or

```
page.xpath("//p[@class='numbRating']")
```

(for all 3) but both of these return empty sets (I am using Scrapy but ran into the same issue using requests and lxml). When I pull larger blocks of the page, the ratings aren't there. They appear where I would expect when I right click and "inspect element" (I'm using Chrome), but they're gone when I look at the source HTML of the page.

I assume there's some kind of javascript magic going on. My question is, how do I get those numbers? Is there an easy way to solve this problem in general? How can the number appear on the page but not in the raw code?

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear when you "view source" but does appear when you "inspect element" because those values are loaded through ajax after most elements have already rendered.  If using Google Chrome, go into the developer tools click the "Network" tab and select "XHR".  Click on the "GetUserReviewSummary......" and view the Response.  You will see that all of the values have been returned here.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question - it doesn't work because it expect a value and requests that data dynamically from a different endpoint.

You could use that endpoint as a workaround though to get what you want:

`http://www.webmd.com/drugs/service/UserRatingService.asmx/GetUserReviewSummary?repositoryId=1&secondaryId=-1&secondaryIdValue=All%20reviews,%20conditions%20&amp;%20overall%20rating&primaryId=' + primary_id`

where `primary_id` (in this case `8603`) is really just the `drugid` from the URL you shared above, and shown below:

`http://webmd.com/drugs/drugreview-8603-Celexa+oral.aspx?drugid=8603&drugname=Celexa+oral&sortby=3`

you can use default parameters to return all review combined:

`secondaryId=-1`

&

`secondaryIdValue=All%20reviews,%20conditions%20&amp;%20overall%20rating`

That way you get a simple xml doc returned and you can parse out your values - i did a little test in Jupyter:

[image]